# does testing a website through JMeter actually overload the main server

Tags: jmeter

I am using to test my web server https://buyandbrag.in .
I have tested it for 100 users. But the main server is not showing like it is crowded or not.
I want to  know whether it  is really pressuring the main server(a cloud server I am using).Or just use the client resourse where the tool is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as mentioned you should be monitoring both servers to see how they handle the load. The simplest way to do this is with TOP (if your server OS is *NIX) also you should be watching the network activity i.e. Bandwidth, connection status (time wait, close wait and so on).

Also if your using apache keep an eye on the logs you should see the requests being logged there

Good luck with the tests

Comment: I want to know "how many users my website can handele ?",when I tested with 50 threads ,the cpu usage of my server increased but not the connections log(It showed just 2 connections).also the bandwidth usage is not that much.....

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know "how many users my website can handele ?",when I tested with 50 threads ,the cpu usage of my server increased but not the connections log(It showed just 2 connections).also the bandwidth usage is not that much

Firstly what connections are you referring to? Apache, DB etc?

Secondly if you want to see how many users your current setup can hand you need to create a profile or traffic model of what an average user will do on your site.

For example:

```
Say 90% of the time they will search for something
5% of the time they will purchase x
5% of the time they login.
```

Once you have your "Traffic Model" defined, implement it in jMeter then start increasing your load in increments i.e. running your load test for 10mins with x users, after 10mins increment that number and so on until you find your breaking point.

If you graph your responses you should see two main things:

1) The optimum response time / number of users before the service degrades
2) The tipping point i.e. at what point you start returning 503's etc

Now you'll have enough data to scale your site or to start making performance improvements from a code point of view.